# Communication between .NET WebApp and MQTT broker

Tags: .net, web-applications, mqtt, iot

I am creating an application that should get and set values ​​from devices like furnaces.
The user should have access to the application with a browser. I made front in Angular SPA and backend API in .NET core.
Communication with the device is to be via MQTT.
I don't know how to make communication between a broker and API backend.

It seems to me that the backend should only show data from the SQL database. It would take too long time for user to download data from the device each time the user refreshes the API page, and secondly I would not have historical data from the device.

I invented, such a solution that I create new App which runs in the background and will receive data from the broker and save it in the SQL database. If I went this way, I would like to have everything communication in this application (get and set).

So my question is:
How to communicate such an new application with the API? (how to reply from new app to API that the action was successful)
Is it worth separating communication with the broker to a new application?
Should communication with broker be in API app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to depict your application flow.

You have added MQTT broker, the device will continuously send data and webjob will continuously process data independently. When you will perform some action from Device to cloud or Cloud to device you don't need to reply immediately.

If you want to send some command (like on/off application) then you can create another mqtt topic which will listen and perform accordingly. both side (device and job) you have to create mqtt listener.

[image]